# WHO's Defined Daily Dose guidelines

Tags: data-request, medical

On the off chance, anyone know where to get an opensource copy of WHO's Anatomical Therapeutic Chemical (ATC) Defined Daily Dose (DDD) guidelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ATC index DDD is copyright protected, so I do not believe one could legally make an open-data version.

You can find information on their licensing on this FAQ page:

http://www.who.int/classifications/help/FAQOther/en/index.html

You can find their copyright statement at:

http://www.who.int/about/copyright/en/