# A database of drugs and their targets

Tags: data-request, medical

Do you know if there is any free for commercial and non-commercial project database with drugs information and their targets?

For example:

```
Drug name: Paracetamol 
Chemical Formula: C8H9NO2
Target: Antipyretics
```

Comment: I answered a related question on this topic awhile back ago: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/whos-defined-daily-dose-guidelines

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

DrugBank: http://www.drugbank.ca/

openFDA API to get some data online:   http://open.fda.gov/

Comment: OpenFDA's APIs are now live. You will probably need a combination of the label and report endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

See also Wikidata. Recent publication "Wikidata, A platform for data integration and dissemination for the life sciences and beyond"
http://www.swat4ls.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/SWAT4LS_2015_paper_38.pdf